# Return Obj-C blocks in C++ code

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, ios, objective-c-blocks

I'm currently porting some classes from the Apple iOS Foundation Framework to C++ and i'm expecting some issues. I'm trying to port this Obj-C method from the NSExpression @class :

```
- (id, NSArray *, NSMutableDictionary *)expressionBlock
```

So in my sfExpression class, I have the following code (when deleting others methods ^^)

```
class sfExpression : public sfObject {
public:
    id (^ExpressionBlock())(id, NSArray*, NSMutableDictionary*);

private:
    NSExpression* _Expression;
};
```

And when I'm trying to implement this function like this :

```
id (^sfExpression::ExpressionBlock())(id, NSArray*, NSMutableDictionary*) {
    return [_Expression expressionBlock];
}
```

It doesn't work... Any ideas ?

I've tried many things but... without success :'(

**EDIT : The code is right. Just switch to LLVM Compiler instead of GCC**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: Moral of the story, don't use GCC when dealing with blocks.**

Here is a full example as far as I can see, this works in my tests.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(NSExpression *_exp) : expression([_exp retain])
    {

    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        [expression release];
    }

    id (^ExpressionBlock())(id, NSArray*, NSMutableDictionary*);
private:
    NSExpression *expression;
};

id (^Foo::ExpressionBlock())(id, NSArray*, NSMutableDictionary*)
{
    return [expression expressionBlock];
}


int main()
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    Foo a([NSExpression expressionForBlock:^id(id evaluatedObject, NSArray *expressions, NSMutableDictionary *context) {
        return evaluatedObject;
    } arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Test"]]);
    NSLog(@"%@", a.ExpressionBlock()(@"Hello", nil, nil));
    [pool drain];
}
```

Comment: Compiler return :

error: cannot convert 'void (^)(objc_object*, NSArray*, NSMutableDictionary*)' to 'objc_object* (^)(objc_object*, NSArray*, NSMutableDictionary*)' in return

Comment: It works only with LLVM Compiler 2.0.

LLVM GCC 4.2 & GCC 4.2 return the error i've copied 3mins ago.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let me guess, your'e using GCC? You should switch to using LLVM if your'e dealing with blocks. GCC doesn't support them properly

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/include/Block.h` manipulates ObjC blocks using opaque void pointers, so that's probably what you should use to pass them around to C++ code if you can't compile it with a compiler supporting blocks. Also take note of the Block_copy and Block_release functions in that header. There's also [an article on memory management of ObjC blocks](http://thirdcog.eu/pwcblocks/).

Comment: I have to use void pointers ? Pointing on the block ?
Can you make an exemple because i'm confused... I already read the article but there is somethings that i've don't understood.
(Hope you understand my poor english... I'm a french guy...)